# How to say 0.01% in a formal way?

Tags: numbers, listening

How do you say 0.01%?

I heard this from NBR which starts at 04:06

[Nightly Business Report](https://youtu.be/MA-Zlc9GR8U?t=4m6s)

Does he say

> one, one hundred percent

or

> one, one hundredth of percent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [one-hundredth](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/one-hundredth)
>   the second decimal digit in a percentage

In our case, **one** (1) is the second decimal digit. So it should be

> one one-hundredth of a percent

This is exactly what he says.

Comment: Hi @Max. I think I should spend more time googling it and spend less time asking questions like this. Not try to answer all questions immediately though they are not few. Just put them on hold for a while. Maybe it is a better way for learners like us. Just want to say it's nice to see you again here.